# Pyinstaller unable to find module when frozen

Tags: python, pyinstaller, hug

This is what I have:

```
├── demo
│   ├── mypkg
│   │   └── __main__.py
│   │   └── api.py
│   │   └── startserver.py
│   └── readme.md
```

api.py has =>

```
import hug
@hug.get('/ping')
def ping():
    return {"response": "pong"}
```

startserver.py has =>

```
def start():
    
  try:
    currentpath = Path(__file__)
    print(f'Currently executing from {currentpath}')
    apipath = os.path.join(currentpath.parent, 'api.py')
    print(f'parse api path is {apipath}')
    print('inside startserver start()')
    with open('testapi.log', 'w') as fd:
        subprocess.run(['hug', '-f', apipath], stdout=fd , stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, bufsize=0)
  except Exception:
     print(traceback.format_exc())
```

`__main.py__` has =>

```
import traceback
from mypkg.startserver import start

def main():
    try:
        start()
    except Exception:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('... inside name == main ...')
    main()
```

When doing "python -m mypkg" from vscode terminal, this works great, hug web server is running and browser can see /ping results in localhost

But when I create a executable (single file exe on Windows 10) using pyinstaller I get this error:

```
Currently executing from 

C:\Users\JOHN~1.KOL\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI442282\mypkg\startserver.pyc
parse api path is C:\Users\JOHN~1.KOL\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI442282\mypkg\api.py
inside startserver start()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypkg\startserver.py", line 16, in start
  File "subprocess.py", line 548, in run
  File "subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

seems like there is no `C:\Users\JOHN~1.KOL\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI442282\mypkg\api.py`
I even tried to change api.py to api.pyc still no luck. How do I get a reference to api.py which is pretty much required to start the hug web server? I have seen other solutions here for missing config files and binary files, but this one is a .py file itself thats needed.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the "hug" command is in the PATH when you execute this?  That's what it is complaining about.

Comment: Tim, this is what I see 
sys.path is .. ['C:\\Users\\JOHN~1.KOL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI216442\\base_library.zip', 'C:\\Users\\JOHN~1.KOL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI216442\\lib-dynload', 'C:\\Users\\JOHN~1.KOL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI216442']

I built executable with "pyinstaller testserve.py --collect-all hug  --onefile"
The collect-all hug is probably not necessary, dunno. Based on all that not sure if hug is on the path! No build errors were there for generating exe. Runs fine in terminal directly, fails while running pyinstaller generated .exe
 Is there something I should check?

Comment: maybe it needs some C/C++ library

Comment: you could use `os.listdir()` or `os.walk()` to list all files during running. And you will see if it has all files and if they are in main folder or in subfolder.

Comment: OK, but where is the "hug" command located?  That's not part of your executable.

Comment: maybe you have to add manually file `hug` to `pyinstaller` because it is normal script which is not in folder with modules. OR maybe there is method to run server directly in code without using `hug` - similar to `Flask` which needs `app.run()` in code instead of external `flask run`

Comment: on my Linux I have `hug` in `/usr/local/bin/hug` (I found it with Linux command `which hug`). But it has code `from hug import development_runner` and `development_runner.hug.interface.cli()` which probably you could run directly in your code. Eventually it may need to add `sys.argv.append('-f')`  `sys.argv.append(apipath)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command `hug` is separated script and it is not in Pythons folder - so `pyinstaller` may not find it and it can't add it to `exe`. You may have to manually add it (probably using file `spec`)

On Linux I have `hug` in `/usr/local/bin/hug`.

I found it with Linux command `which hug`.

---

But  file `hug` is normal python script which import module `hug` and it runs it.

```
from hug import development_runner 
development_runner.hug.interface.cli()
```

You could do the same without using `subprocess` and you will no need to add file `hug` to `exe`.

You may have to only append `-f` and `apipath` to `sys.argv`

This start `hug` for me:

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from hug import development_runner 

currentpath = Path(__file__)
apipath = os.path.join(currentpath.parent, 'api.py')
    
sys.argv.append('-f')
sys.argv.append(apipath)

development_runner.hug.interface.cli()
```

Comment: Thank you so very much furas for digging in like that, I very much appreciate it! Yes, pyinstaller produced a working executable. The key was the development_runner you pointed to. I ended up skipping the cli () entirely, eliminating any need for path to a file in frozen mode.

Comment: I too dug in, saw in git that inputs to hug are defined in this way
`def hug(

    file: "A Python file that contains a Hug API" = None,

    module: "A Python module that contains a Hug API" = None,

    host: "Interface to bind to" = "",

    port: number = 8000,

    no_404_documentation: boolean = False,

    manual_reload: boolean = False,

    interval: number = 1,

    command: "Run a command defined in the given module" = None,

    silent: boolean = False,

):`

Comment: later also saw this:
`if file and module:
        print("Error: can not define both a file and module source for Hug API.")
        sys.exit(1)`

So, skipping file path and passing in module name did the trick:
`development_runner.hug(None,"mypkg.myapi") `

pyinstaller needed "--collect-all hug" switch

Comment: Maybe you should describe it as answer. It can be useful for other users. And later you can mark your answer as accepted :)

Comment: furas I already marked your answer as accepted, that stays :)  But yes I will post my comment above as additional nicely formatted answer also, thats a good idea. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on furas idea above, we see that hug in git source code defines these inputs:

```
def hug(

    file: "A Python file that contains a Hug API" = None,

    module: "A Python module that contains a Hug API" = None,

    host: "Interface to bind to" = "",

    port: number = 8000,

    no_404_documentation: boolean = False,

    manual_reload: boolean = False,

    interval: number = 1,

    command: "Run a command defined in the given module" = None,

    silent: boolean = False,

):
```

we also see that either a path to a file or a module can be passed in:

```
if file and module:

    print("Error: can not define both a file and module source for Hug API.")

    sys.exit(1)
```

So, skipping cli() and file path requirement completely and passing in module name did the trick: `development_runner.hug(None,"mypkg.myapi")  pyinstaller`

it also needed the pyinsaller "collect-all hug" switch. Resultant exe works like a charm, thanks everyone!